# KNIME SDF Reader maybe uses default workflow variable value even if overridden via batch mode parameter

Tags: java, knime

I'm calling a KNIME workflow in [batch mode](https://tech.knime.org/faq#q12), providing the path to an SDF input file via flow variable parameter:

```
-workflow.variable=template.sdf,C:\correct\path\template.sdf,String
```

The SDF Reader Node seems to try to use the default workflow variable value first. It then proceeds without error, apparently using the value I passed in via batch parameter.

Is that just a logging issue or a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the initial call to the node configure method during workflow loading happens with the default value before the value passed from the batch command is applied hence seeing the console warning before the workflow then runs ok